# What is the table structure for seat arrangement in online movie ticket booking?

Tags: database

Database question i have problem with creating the of seat arrangement for online movie ticket booking. what is the structure of the table? how i can arrange the seat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a table where there is a column like **id**, **row_id**, **seat_id**, **seat_category**

Then you can easily keep information about seats.

When a user book a seat, you need to keep the information in other table where you use the **id** of the **seat** table.

Based on you application requirement, this could be complex, but in simplest case this should do the job

Comment: if we have to arrange the seat structure with space between to column so what we can do?

Comment: giving an example will help me to understand the problem

Comment: in theater there is different class tickets.the space for exit and entrance between seats.that haw to manage?